# Get serialized output of a page and then convert it

Tags: php

i have a serialized output  from a CURL posted form

you can check the output here

```
http://shopnineteen.com/new-admin/payu.php
```

The output is a return of the CURL form action url

i want to capture this output and unserialized it

how i can do that ?

Comment: What is the format of this output ? is this json ?

Comment: @MoyedAnsari It is a serialized PHP array.  http://php.net/serialize

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you were after, but here is a very simple cURL request for that URL, and then it unserializes the result.

```
<?php

$url = 'http://shopnineteen.com/new-admin/payu.php';

$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

if ($result) {
    $data = unserialize($result);

    if (!$data) {
        echo "Not valid serialized data.";
    } else {
        var_dump($data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the string is in `JSON` format

use [JSON DECODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

and you can whatever you want to to with the data

Comment: It is actually a serialized PHP array, not JSON.  Similar but not valid JSON.